# Is the following function $g$ integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Is the following function $g$ integrable?

Define $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ by 
$$f(x)= \begin{cases} \frac{1}{\sqrt x}& 0<x<1\\0 &\text{else}\end{cases}$$

Let $r_n$ be an enumeration of all rationals: define $g:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ by 
$$
g(x)=\sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}f(x-r_n).
$$

Now surely $f$ is integrable since set of discontinuities of $f$ has measure $0$: how to show that this is true for $g$?

Please help.

Comment: If it is not specified how the rationals are enumerated, I doubt that the function $g(x)$ is well-defined. I am also not sure whether the integrability depends of the specific enumeration.

Comment: @Peter,But this is what has been given

Comment: Probably, it can be shown that $g(x)$ is integrable no matter how the enumeration looks like, but I do not know how to prove it. I think it has to do with the fact that the set of rational numbers has measure $0$.

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about integrability in the Lebesgue sense this is quite easy: $\int g(x)\, dx= \int \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {2^{k}} \int f(x-r_n)\, dx= \int \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {2^{k}} \int f(x)\, dx=\int f(x)\, dx <\infty$. The second equality is by Fubini/Tonelli (applicable because $f \geq 0$) and the third equality is by translation invariance of Lebesgue measure. Alternate proof of second inequality: $\int \sum g_n =\sum \int g_n $ for any sequence of non-negative measurable functions $\{g_n\}$ because $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} g_k$ increases to $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} g_k$ and we can apply Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Comment: Maybe you could add that the computation is legit as is because $f$ is nonnegative?

Comment: @Mindlack I have added that.

Comment: I cant accept your answer because we have not studied Fubini/Tonelli still ,can u please solve it using elementary terms

Comment: @Join_PhD The Monotone Convergence Theorem shows that if $f_n\ge0$ then $\int\sum f-_n=\sum\int f_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about the Riemann integral or the Lebesgue integral?

If the Lebesgue integral then yes, it's integrable. When you say "Now surely $f$ is integrable since set of discontinuities of $f$ has measure $0$" it almost sounds like you're talking about the Riemann integral. In fact $f$ is *not* Riemann integrable: The theorem is that if $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ is *bounded* and continuous except on a set of measure zero then it's Riemann integrable.

Comment: Yes I am talking about Riemann integral